# Javascript: What is the best option to execute multiple true functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

I need to run a function that will check for multiple values at once and run all functions that return as a true statement.
These values are intertwined and IF/ELSE can't do it cause it stops at the first code that gets a return of true.
Where I need it to go down and check to see if more of such IF lines might also be true, then run those as well.
Finally if it runs the whole list of options and all return as false then it needs to run an all false code line.

The reason for this is I am creating a skill tree.
This tree branches out and branches together at points along the tree.

My best guess is to combine switch with array, but this is more complicated than anything I have programmed so am unsure.
Unfortunately every tutorial I find with switch has switch end after it returns one true and run a single function.

example

IF true run function

IF true run function

IF false ignore

IF false ignore

IF false ignore

IF true run function

IF false ignore

IF false ignore

IF all were false run function

Comment: Can you clarify "run all functions that return as a true statement"? This would imply that you have to run the function to know if you must run the function.

Comment: `multiple values at once` you mean one after the other, sequentially, because javascript is single task at a time - as is, your question is at best too broad, but pretty much unlcear - you'll have to post some details

Comment: Storing all the if result in an array?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know if:

*either some tests are true*

```
var someTrue = ArrayOfFunctionTests.some(function(test) {
    return test()
})
```

*or every test is false*

```
var allFalse = ArrayOfFunctionTests.every(function(test) {
    return !test()
})
```

The are both the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tests = [true, false, true, false], // test results
    funcs = [act0, act1, act2, act3],   // functions to conditionally run
    allFalse = true

tests.each(function(result, index) {
    if (result) funcs[index]()          // conditionally run function
    if (result) allFalse = false        // not allFalse if any is true
})

if (allFalse) finalFunction()           // final condional function
```